# JQqplot chart not rendering after an ajaxpost

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

i am drawing a chart in two different scenarios. first scenario is during on load and the second one is after on success of the ajax post. same code is  calling in both scenarios
during the onload function the chart is correctly loading by using jqplot. but after posting the error is showing on the client side

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'BarRenderer' of undefined
```

the script refernce are loading in the order

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.jqplot.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js" type="text/javascript">    
<script src="../../Scripts/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js" type="text/javascript">  </script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../../Content/jquery.jqplot.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jqplot.ohlcRenderer.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jqplot.highlighter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it sounds like your ajax post is returning script tags along with content you need.

those script tags probably contain jquery which overwrites your jquery and causes many of your plugins to fail.

make sure the content returned by the post doesnt contain your script tags

Comment: Thanks this code is working... my post was returning a script. when i removed it is properly working